# Unable to create 'path/to/repo/external/.git/index.lock': Permission denied

Tags: python, git, ubuntu

I am running a python command that generates some code and checks out some commits using git. However an exception is raised when it tries to create the file .git/index.lock. Root owns the directory so I can't create any file without sudo.

I have tried running the command with sudo (sudo ./run.py ). This also didn't work because then it can't find my ssh key. Can I get around this without changing the ownership of .git, and without creating a root ssh key? Both of these things I do not want. I have seen similar questions like these but none of those answers works here.

```sh
fatal: Unable to create '/path/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 155 in <module>
  ...
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418 in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'reset', '--hard', <hash>]' returned non-zero exist status 128.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to perform any Git checkouts without permissions to write to the repository. However, if you want to use your SSH key, you can try running with `sudo -E` instead of plain `sudo`. That will ask sudo to preserve your home directory and any agent variables, which will let you use your SSH key.

Note that on some systems, the ability to preserve the environment is disabled or restricted, and consequently this won't work in those cases. In such an environment, you'd need to edit `/etc/sudoers` or use some other technique for credentials (such as a root-owned credential store and HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Your have to clone git repository using http or https.
And execute below command:
git config —global credential.helper wincred
git fetch 
First time it will ask for password and save it.
Next execution of git fetch it will not ask password.

Note: In case of password change you have to do same thing.